# How to fetch Rundeck Job output through terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal, script, shell-script

The purpose of my code is to download the output log generated by a specific rundeck job number, that is hosted on my local rundeck server.

So I tried using

```
curl -o output.txt -0 https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx/project/Project-Folder/execution/show/25139#output
```

However, when I do this, the file `output.txt` has no info, and is basically empty.

Is there some other way? I can fetch the output of a rundeck job with it's exec number, through terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got to a conclusion after a little looking around and fiddling the way to fetch the output would be to run this command as a local command:

```
cat /var/lib/rundeck/logs/rundeck/${job.project}/job/${job.id}/logs/${job.execid}.rdlog
```

This should output the log.